# Merge two dataframe if one string column is contained in another column in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge the following `df1` and `df2`, based on condition: if `address` in `df1` contains `state` in `df2`.

**df1:**

```
                                                                           address  \
0      Cecilia Chapman 711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96522 (257) 563-7401   
1  Iris Watson P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska 20620 (372) 587-2335   
2    Celeste Slater 606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 11523 (786) 713-8616   
3            Theodore Lowe Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39531 (793) 151-6230   
4                 Calista Wise 7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 47096 (492) 709-6392   

   quantity  price  
0         2     20  
1         3     13  
2         5     23  
3         3     32  
4         5     45
```

**df2:**

```
   id        state
0   1  Mississippi
1   2     Nebraska
2   3     New York
```

My expected output will like this. How could I do that? Thank you.

```
                                                                           address  \
0      Cecilia Chapman 711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mississippi 96522 (257) 563-7401   
1  Iris Watson P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Frederick Nebraska 20620 (372) 587-2335   
2    Celeste Slater 606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Roseville NH 11523 (786) 713-8616   
3            Theodore Lowe Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New York 39531 (793) 151-6230   
4                 Calista Wise 7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 47096 (492) 709-6392   

   quantity  price   id        state  
0         2     20  1.0  Mississippi  
1         3     13  2.0     Nebraska  
2         5     23  NaN          NaN  
3         3     32  3.0     New York  
4         5     45  NaN          NaN
```

**Update:** the output of `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['state']);
print(df1['address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False))`

```
      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  ...    40   41   42  \
0    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN   
1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN   
2    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN   
3    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN    
..   ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ...   ...  ...  ...  
158  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN   
159  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all possible states by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `\b\b` for words boundaries to new column and then `merge` with left join:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['state'])
df1['state']= df1['address'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df1)
                                             address  quantity  price  \
0  Cecilia Chapman 711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mis...         2     20   
1  Iris Watson P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Freder...         3     13   
2  Celeste Slater 606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Ro...         5     23   
3  Theodore Lowe Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New Yo...         3     32   
4  Calista Wise 7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 47...         5     45   

         state  
0  Mississippi  
1     Nebraska  
2          NaN  
3     New York  
4          NaN  

df = df1.merge(df2, on='state', how='left')
print (df)
                                             address  quantity  price  \
0  Cecilia Chapman 711-2880 Nulla St. Mankato Mis...         2     20   
1  Iris Watson P.O. Box 283 8562 Fusce Rd. Freder...         3     13   
2  Celeste Slater 606-3727 Ullamcorper. Street Ro...         5     23   
3  Theodore Lowe Ap #867-859 Sit Rd. Azusa New Yo...         3     32   
4  Calista Wise 7292 Dictum Av. San Antonio MI 47...         5     45   

         state   id  
0  Mississippi  1.0  
1     Nebraska  2.0  
2          NaN  NaN  
3     New York  3.0  
4          NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand two `parenthese` in `str.extract('('+ ... + ')'`, could you explain more?

Comment: @ahbon - it is because matching regex pattern need `(regex)`, so added `()` to `pat`

Comment: Sorry, I get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 50, placement implies 1` with real data, any ideas?

Comment: @ahbon Is possible some non alphabet or space values in `df2['state']`?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible test if change `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in df2['state'])` to `import re`  and `pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(re.escape(x)) for x in df2['state'])` ?

Comment: If the datafame is in Chinese, it will not work out. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60219423/merge-if-one-column-contained-in-another-column-in-python.

Comment: @ahbon - Unfortunately I have no experience with chinese text processing, so cannot halp with it.

Comment: No problem. Thank you. :) But I think the logic should be same, except English characters have more space to split words.